# Copy a sqlite table from assets to data/data in Android

Tags: android

I am making a function that provides sqlite database update. I have a database(such as demo.db) in assets folder that is copied to my data folder when I enter the Android App for the first time. However, when I have a new version for my app, I need to replace a sqlite table in the assets folder which has already been created in the data/data folder.Here is my code:

MySQLiteHelpter extends SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        for(int i = oldVersion; i <=  newVersion; i++){
            switch (i){
                case 8:
                    //delete the older table 
                    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + DFY_BD_DISTRICT);

                    //do something.
                    //I need to copy the table from the assets folder even I have already created the database in the previous version.

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my code I use to copy my database to data/data folder for the first time:

```
public static void loadDB(Context context, String dbName) {
    String packName = context.getPackageName();
    String dbPath = "data/data/" + packName + "/databases";

    try {
        File e = new File(dbPath);
        if(!e.exists()) {
            e.mkdirs();
        }

        File dest = new File(e, dbName);
        if(dest.exists()) {
            return;
        }

        dest.createNewFile();
        InputStream in = context.getResources().getAssets().open(dbName);
        int size = in.available();
        byte[] buf = new byte[size];
        in.read(buf);
        in.close();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        out.write(buf);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception var10) {
        var10.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

As I have searched on the Internet,I have found some question similar to mine:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264860/android-sqlite-database-copying-table-from-assets-to-local-app-database
I am glad that if you can give me some help   : )
If you need more code or more question,I will paste my code as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to copy the local asset database to the android device.

```
String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.app/databases/"


public String initialiseDB(String dbName,String copyas,Context context)
    {

        try
        {               
            File f = new File(DB_PATH);
            if (!f.exists())
            {
                f.mkdir();
            }

            // Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(dbName);

            // File for creating the database
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + copyas;

            File tmpFile = new File(outFileName);


            // check if the database already exist

            if (!tmpFile.exists()){
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, outFileName + "database not available, initialising seed");
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }



            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
}


        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            return "failure";
        }

        return "SUCCESS";

    }
```

I hope this will help you...Let me know if you have any trouble to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you for your code~  But your code seems to copy the database for the first time  I enter the App rather than copying a table in the database form the assets to the data/data folder~

Comment: In your case,@LinaInverce ---- you can delete the old db data in the update and copy the new db from the assets programmatically.

Comment: My question is the same with @LinaInverce 's question. I don't want to transfer file completely but just transfer a table to my database file. I am sure this is possible but still couldn't find an answer. I am trying to write code in onCreate function to do this.